# Ajax - html(data) when data is inside structure logic (if/else)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My problem is about like unlike system. So if a like button is clicked, will appear a remove like button and otherwise, with data appended via ajax. I know to create an ajax via jquery, but my data is inside structure logic (if & else).

This is my code :

```
<?php 
        echo '<div class="clearfix">
        ';
        echo '<div class="pull-right" id="like-unlike-status'.$idStatus.'">
        ';
        $queryLikeStatus = $this->Member->likeStatus($idStatus,$id);
        $queryUnlikeStatus = $this->Member->unlikeStatus($idStatus,$id);

        $likeStatus = $queryLikeStatus->row_array();
        $dataLikeStatus[] = $likeStatus;

        $unlikeStatus = $queryUnlikeStatus->row_array();
        $dataUnlikeStatus[] = $unlikeStatus;

        foreach($dataLikeStatus as $likedStatus);
        foreach($dataUnlikeStatus as $unlikedStatus);
        $exLikers = explode(',', $likedStatus['user_like_status']);
        $exUnlikers = explode(',', $unlikedStatus['user_unlike_status']);
        $countLike = $likedStatus['like_status_count'];
        $countUnlike = $unlikedStatus['unlike_status_count'];
        echo '<span class="black margin-right10" style="font-size:10px">';
        if(!in_array($uid, $exUnlikers)){
         if(in_array($uid, $exLikers)){
            echo '<a id="delete-like-status'.$idStatus.'" role="button" onclick="deleteLikeStatus('.$idStatus.')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Batal suka" class="like_status"><b class="app fontsize-xxhigh mdi mdi-thumb-up padding-right5"></b></a>';
         }
         else{
            echo '<a id="add-like-status'.$idStatus.'" role="button" onclick="likeStatus('.$idStatus.')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Suka" class="like_status">
            <b class="grey fontsize-high mdi mdi-thumb-up padding-right5"></b></a>';
         }
        }
        else{
            echo '<a id="like-status'.$idStatus.'" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Suka" class="like_status" disabled="disabled">
            <b class="grey fontsize-high mdi mdi-thumb-up padding-right5"></b></a>';
        }
        if (empty($countLike) || $countLike == 0) {
            echo '<b class="app" title="Belum ada yg menyukai" data-toggle="tooltip" role="button">'.renumber(0).'</b>';
        }
        else {
         echo '<b class="app" id="liker-status'.$idStatus.'" role="button">'.renumber($countLike).'</b>';
        ?>

        <?php
        }
        echo '</sapn>
        <span class="black margin-right10" style="font-size:10px">';
        if(!in_array($uid, $exLikers)){
        if(in_array($uid, $exUnlikers)){
            echo '<a id="unlike-status'.$idStatus.'" role="button" href="'.site_url("proses/delete_unlike/".$idStatus).'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Batal tidak suka" class="unlike_status"><b class="red fontsize-xxhigh mdi mdi-thumb-down padding-right5"></b></a>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<a id="unlike-status'.$idStatus.'" role="button" href="'.site_url("proses/add_unlike/".$idStatus).'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tidak suka" class="unlike_status">
            <b class="grey fontsize-high mdi mdi-thumb-down padding-right5"></b></a>';
        } 
        }
        else{
            echo '<a id="unlike-status'.$idStatus.'" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tidak suka" class="unlike_status" disabled="disabled">
            <b class="grey fontsize-high mdi mdi-thumb-down padding-right5"></b></a>';
        }
        if (empty($countUnlike) || $countUnlike == 0) {
            echo '<b class="red" title="Belum ada yg tidak menyukai" data-toggle="tooltip" role="button">'.renumber(0).'</b>';
        }
        else {
         echo '<b class="red" id="unliker-status'.$idStatus.'" role="button">'.renumber($countUnlike).'</b>';
        ?>

        <?php
        }
        echo '</span>';

        echo '</div>';

            echo '<div class="pull-left">
            <span class="black sans time-status-'.$idStatus.'" style="padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:2.5px; font-size:10px"></span>
            </div>

        </div>';
```

My above code is just part of all codes, Help me to solve my problem.

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: My question is how to parsing data / html(data) via ajax in code above, so if 'add like' is clicked will be inserted to the database and automatically moved to 'delete like' section. Then if 'remove like' is clicked, data of 'add like' will be deleted and automatically moved to 'add like' section. and countinues like that. I tried to make that, but when data has inserted, not automatically moved to next section like i said above. Hope any solution for that  :-)

Comment: You could return the HTML and then replace the HTML, or implement the changes in javascript by having a dedicated endpoint for like/unlike state, then return json for js to handle updating the dom.

Comment: As its only 2 states (like/unlike), it would be easy to look up what state it was and toggle between them on click.

Comment: So i must do with replaceWith() function ? but i have idea too, with automatically reloading with setInterval() function, but what is the better of those two ?

Comment: if with toggleClass() or addclass and removeclass is cant moving to next section too